# Android custom status notification view height

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've made a customer status bar notification according to the Android Developer's Guide. I wanted to create a custom expanded view since the default would cut off my content. I was able to mock up something similar to the default view, but my content gets cutoff as it's height goes beyond the height of the notification area.

Is there a way to expand the height of the notification expanded view for my status bar notification via the layout or some means when declaring the notification (in a service in this case)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to expand the height of the notification expanded view for my status bar notification via the layout or some means when declaring the notification (in a service in this case)?

Nope, sorry.

[From Android developers group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b7bf5d6fc7f4c76b/), Dianne Hackborn says:

> No the height is deliberately restricted.